# Get options for jQuery modal

Tags: javascript, jquery, modal-dialog

I'm using a modal dialog from this library: https://github.com/kylefox/jquery-modal.  I'd like to get and/or update the options property of an open modal but couldn't see any built in way to do so.

As a workaround I added a function in the source like this:

```
$.modal.options = function() {
    return getCurrent().options;
}
```

This works but I'm wondering if there is already and existing method of doing this without adding that function.

Comment: From the look of that plugin it does not support updating the options after initialisation. I would suggest you use another one, such as the standard one provided by the Bootstrap library or the Colorbox plugin.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan - For my purposes this modal is actually working really great as is and with the function I added it's fine - just that I'm a bit new to extending jquery and wasn't sure if I was doing something unnecessary here by adding a function and if I could in fact access the object properties somehow without doing so..  Thanks for your input!